# Google Storage - POST - Trouble With Generating Security Policy

Tags: php, json, forms, google-cloud-storage

I am creating the following form for using the POST object with Google Storage to allow a user to upload a document to my bucket. I am getting the following error when I submit the form. I am sure I am creating my policy wrong, but I am unsure how to do it correctly, I've tried several ways. [Google's documentation explains the policy here](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/reference-methods.html#postobject). Thank you for your help!

```
    <Error> 

<Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code> − <Message> The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document. </Message> 
− <Details> Invalid value for conditions: {"acl":"private","failure_action_redirect":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/failure_instructions.html"} </Details> 
</Error>


class Policy {
    public $expiration = "2010-12-31T11:11:11Z";
    public $conditions = array("acl" => "private",
                        "failure_action_redirect" => "http://www.example.com/failure_instructions.html");
}
$policy = new Policy();
$policy = json_encode($policy);

$policy_utf = utf8_encode($policy);
$policy_base64 = base64_encode($policy_utf);
$policy_sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $policy_base64, $secret, TRUE));
?>

<form action="http://<example_bucket>.commondatastorage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="test_documenttttt">
            <input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<?php echo $policy_base64; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $policy_sig; ?>">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
</form>
```

Comment: I've tried not having any conditions, or having conditions = "", and that won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

It was as simple as the tutorial makes it - I was looking into it too much. Simply set `$policy = <the code>` and UTF-8 encode it. My problem was I would set  `$policy = <the example code>` , but then I would json_encode() that. It's already `JSON` encoded, so JSON encoding that messed it up. My fault for reading too
much into it!

```
$policy = '{ "expiration": "2010-12-31T11:11:11Z",'.
                        '"conditions": ['.
                        '["starts-with", "$key", "" ],'.
                '{"acl": "private" }'.
                        ']'.
                        '}';
```

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ i am trying to upload a file using Google app engine in the Google cloud storage. I am using java for it. Can you please tell me what is $key value in the above statement $policy. Waiting for your favourable response.